# python, 2 operations: find closest value above and below a specified value in array, find associated values in another array

Tags: python

python question:
I have 2 columns of data, an independent and dependent variable. I want to be able to look up the nearest value above & the nearest value below a value of my choosing from the independent variable array.  So if my independent variable is just a list of numbers [1,2,3,4,5,6...], I want a routine that will return 2 as the low value and 3 as the high value if I query about the value 2.44.

PART 2: Once I have those values identified, I want to look up the associated values from my dependent variable. So if my dependent variable was 5x my dependent it would be [5, 10, 15, 20...].  I would like a routine that would return the associated values from the last step.  The last step returned 2 & 3. In this example the associated values would be 10 & 15.

Thanks All...

Comment: It's generally good practice to try something first, instead of just asking people to do it for you.

Comment: You missed the most important 2 pieces of information. The first is the code that you already tried, and the second is the size of the lists. If the lists are small enough you should just sort them to make the lookup more easily.

Comment: @Blubber: You can do that anyway. You can make the lookup faster by bisecting if the list is big though.

Comment: I think a simple solutions is in order first. Making it faster is likely not a big concern compared to getting something at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have list of numbers:

```
In [128]: L
Out[128]: [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

sort them first:

```
In [129]: L.sort()    
In [130]: L
Out[130]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Then do the check:

```
In [131]: for lower, upper in zip(L[:-1], L[1:]):
   .....:     if lower <= 2.44 <= upper:
   .....:         print(lower, upper)
   .....:         break
   .....:         
2 3
```

Adjust the `if lower <= 2.44 <= upper` to reflect if you want upper and lower boundaries inclusive or exclusive.

Please try yourself for the second part.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the first issue perfectly

Comment: Great. Feel free to accept this answer. Than try the second part with some more code. Hint: Multiplication is as simple as typing a `*`.